# How to limit visit times to a method in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

There is a signal--sendMessage(), it will trigger a function--handleMessage(), if I got the signal too many times in a shot time, there will be some issues, so I want to set handleMessage() only can be run one time every 500 ms.

Can some friends kindly tell me how to achieve it?

Comment: Start and reset a timer in sendMessage, that calls handleMessage after 500ms

Comment: Thanks for every friend's help, get it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would do this was to make a member variable `bool mMessageSendPending;`

Next I would make a member variable `QTimer mTimer;`

In constructor, I would set up timer like this:

```
// Run lambda function on timer timeout
connect(&mTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){
    // This code will be run by timer
    if(mMessageSendPending){
        // This will never happen more frequent than 500ms
        handleMessage();
        // Reset to be ready for next send
        mMessageSendPending=false;
    }
});

// Start timer with interval of 500 ms
mTimer.start(500);


// Run lambda function on sendMessage received
connect(&mySender, &MySenderClass::sendMessage, [=](){
    // Mark that we want to handle message.
    // This may happen more frequent than once every 500ms
    mMessageSendPending=true;
});
```

**EDIT:** As @Trevir pointed out, this is not safe across thread boundaries. To make it safe, it is suggested to wrap all access to `mMessageSendPending` in a `QMutexLocker` with matching `QMutex`, or alternatively wrap  `QAtomicInteger` to create an "atomic boolean".

Comment: how about making `mMessageSendPending` atomic?

Comment: This would only make sense in cases where signals are sent across Thread boundaries, right?

Comment: Yes of course, but we don't know in which thread `mySender` lives.

Comment: You are right. Still, the way I see it, it is customary in Qt to not use threads unless there is a specific need to, and instead rely on the ever present event loop. Since O.P. did not mention anything about threads I assumed this was not relevant to the question, and could be avoided.

Comment: Side note: Your solution will poll for messages even if none arrived since last polling.

Comment: (Which is ok if messages are sent all the time, but is not desirable if messages "come in chunks" with longer times between chunks)

Comment: @E4z9: Fair point! I am too lazy to update the answer, please feel free!

Answer (score 1):

A usual way to handle this is to delay your handling of the messages manually, e.g. connect as usual

```
connect(sender, &Sender::sendMessage, receiver, &Receiver::handleMessage);
```

and collect messages on the receiving side, delaying with a timer

```
class Receiver : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void handleMessage(const QString &message);
....
private:
    QStringList m_messages;
....
};

static const int DELAY = 500;

void Receiver::handleMessage(const QString &message)
{
    const bool needsScheduling = m_messages.isEmpty();
    m_messages.append(message);
    if (needsScheduling) {
        // schedule handling messages after a delay
        // calls of handleMessage until this fires will add more messages
        // to m_messages
        QTimer::singleShot(DELAY, this, [this]() {
            // do whatever you need to do with the messages
            qDebug() << m_messages;
            // clean up
            m_messages.clear();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in QML:

```js
Timer {
    id: timer
    property real period: 1000
    property real started: 0
    interval: 10
    running: true
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        var s = new Date().getTime();
        if((s - timer.started) > timer.period)
        {
            timer.started = s;
            handleMessage();

        }
    }

    function handleMessage()
    {
        console.log("handleMessage");
    }
}
```

`handleMessage()` called not often than 1000 ms although `onTriggered()` called every 10 ms.